# DataTable Select not returning values

Tags: c#

I have a datatable and I'm trying to select some of the rows from the datatable.
It works well for PracticeIDs 1 & 37, but for some reason, when it gets to the last row of the data(ID 7), it doesn't pull up the record from the datatable.

Any ideas?

```
        //create datatable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("PracticeID");
        dt.Columns.Add("AuthorID");

        //add data(in real code, this is pulled from the database)
        dt.Rows.Add(1, 87);
        dt.Rows.Add(37, 202);
        dt.Rows.Add(1, 268);
        dt.Rows.Add(7, 262);

        //get distinct practiceids into datatable
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        DataTable dtDistinctIDs = dv.ToTable(true, "PracticeID");

        //for each practice, get a list of the authors
        foreach (DataRow practiceRow in dtDistinctIDs.Rows)
        {

            DataRow[] dra = dt.Select("PracticeID = " + practiceRow["PracticeID"].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: `... it doesn't pull up the record from the datatable.` <= Please be more descriptive. Is there an Exception? Is the loop simply not reaching it? Did your computer freeze? Did .... etc. We cannot see your screen so the only thing that we can do (at this point) is to what happened and then guess why it happened. If there is an Exception please include as much as you can about it (Message, Type, Inner Exceptions). If there is not an exception please detail the behavior. Also update your question with this info, do not create a comment with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was hard to spot, as this behaviour seems counterintuitive. The problem you are experimenting is derived of the columns not having a datatype. I now can't explain it exactly, but try to change your code to the following and it would work as expected:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("PracticeID",typeof(int)); //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT
dt.Columns.Add("AuthorID");

//add data(in real code, this is pulled from the database)
dt.Rows.Add(1, 87);
dt.Rows.Add(37, 202);
dt.Rows.Add(1, 268);
dt.Rows.Add(7, 262);

//get distinct practiceids into datatable
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
DataTable dtDistinctIDs = dv.ToTable(true, "PracticeID");

//for each practice, get a list of the authors
foreach (DataRow practiceRow in dtDistinctIDs.Rows)
{

    DataRow[] dra = dt.Select("PracticeID = " + (int)practiceRow["PracticeID"]);
}
```

**EDIT:**

In fact I was wrong and it was simpler. The real problem was with your `Select` not having `'` surrounding the field, as by default the DataColumn is string. So, using your original code, just changing the following should work:

```
DataRow[] dra = dt.Select("PracticeID = '" + practiceRow["PracticeID"].ToString() + "'");
```

Comment: Or use:         
DataRow[] dra = dt.Select("PracticeID = '" + practiceRow["PracticeID"].ToString() + "'");  - If you want to treat the ID as a string

Comment: Yes @jondow, just was editing when you commented. Thank you :)